# Micro Service cross service dependencies

Tags: architecture, microservices

Just to simplify my situation I currently have 3 micro services.

1. Authentication
2. Locations
3. Inventory

The authentication service authenticates the user and sends back a JWT access token and I use that across the other services. Its stateless and all works well.

I setup locations among some other things in the location service and this works well and as expected.

But now I am at the inventory service and I need to add some inventory but it is linked to a location. I can easily pass the locationId in the API call but I have no way of authorizing the current user to add something to that location unless I then call the location service to validate this.

This then creates service dependencies between each other and it is something I am trying to avoid at all costs otherwise you just lose most of the benefits of micro services.

What would be the recommended approach to validate that the current user has permissions for that location? The only thing I have thought of so far is either

1. Getting the location API to issue out another access token with additional claims of what locations they have access to.
2. Or issuing out another completely separate token of some kind and passing that via the header to the inventory micro service to do a validation similar to how the JWT is authenticated.

**Edit**

As mentioned below on providing aggregate roots (or I am assuming that means the same as API gateways) it would provide the 3rd option of another service on top to communicate to both to provide the information.

However it then leaves a 3rd service dependent upon 2 others, so I just increased my service dependencies.

Comment: Look for `aggregate` and `aggregate root` in google. It is a transactional element that fits perfect for microservices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You microservice design is poor. You are modeling (`location` and `items`) 1 class = 1 microservice and this is not a good idea.

You shoul modeling microservices like `Aggregate Roots` in `DDD`; even with its own bounded context. So, in your case, you should model an `Aggregate Root` with `location`,  `items` and `user` that allows to check domain rules at `item addition user action`. This could be, i.e., in your `Stock Context`.

Of course, this doesn't mean that you should not have a `Wharehouse Context` in wich you can add, modify and/or delete `locations` and (if no need of depencies to check domain rules) the `Aggregate Root` is just `Location class`. But this is other microservice in another context.

This [post](https://www.tigerteam.dk/2014/micro-services-its-not-only-the-size-that-matters-its-also-how-you-use-them-part-2/) should help you. It will bring you a big A-HA! in your mind after reading it.

Comment: I haven't modeled 1 class = 1 micro service. Each service handles its own domain, with many tables but its grouped logically into handling particular functions. Location and Inventory have several models associated with it. But there is a dependency there. The Location Service would also handle location based services for other sections of the app unrelated to inventory.

Comment: Just to add the example is really dumbed down so I could highlight the aspect of cross service dependencies. When I see a cross service dependency the first thing I think of is, I should group it together, but it can't be done in all cases as then I would be combining Inventory, Location and other services all into one, then it just ends up a large monolithic API, with everything together.

Comment: " I would be combining Inventory, Location and other services all into one" My point is not combining services, my point is obtain an Aggregate root from persistence and offer just one microservice with user cases that implies this aggregate root.

Comment: Of course, this will bring a lot of questions about how to handle persistence; same persistence system for all microservices? split into read/write model? independent write model for each service and just one read model?, etc. This, of course, depends of your systems and requirements. Microservices journey is long and take a lot of time and work until everything match up.

Answer (score 0):

While @jlvaquero provided the idea above I just wanted to list what my actual solution was and why.

It then comes down to this setup

[image]

Now the validation is done at a gateway level. The only thing I am having some degree of uncertainty of here is the fact I am now doing validation of an entity outside the service that is meant to be in charge of that domain.

The inventory service is just accepting that the user is allowed to attach to that location. But considering that the location and user validation is outside of the services domain, it fits in that it shouldn't concern itself with that validation.

Comment: If I may ask, I also have started with the Micro Service pattern. Could I trouble you for some advice? I have posted a Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794630/micro-service-security

Answer (score 0):

Gateway should do only authentication and not authorizations.  The authorizations are handled inside the service as the services only maintains who can access it.  I would get the Inventory service to get the list of locations that the user is authorized to access.

The whole orchestration will be happening at the UI level so that the inventory services is not building a hard dependency on the Location service.

This is one approach - not sure if this will work for you.