# Micro service security

Tags: c#, microservices

Over the last few days I've been playing with the micro service pattern and all is going well but security seems to baffle me.

<strike>So If I may ask a question:
How do I handle user authentication on an individual service? At the moment I pass a request to the `Gateway API` which in turns connects to the service.</strike>

**Question Edited Please See Below**

Bearing in mind that the individual services should not know about each other. The `Gateway` is the aggregator as such.

**Current architecture.**

[image]

A little code to simulate the request:

**Frontend - Client App**

```
public class EntityRepository<T>
{
    private IGateway _gateway = null;
    public EntityRepository(IGateway gateway)
    {
        this._gateway = gateway;
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return this._gateway.Get(typeof(T)).Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>().Result;
    }
    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return this._gateway.Get(typeof(T)).Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
    }
    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        this._gateway.Post(typeof(T), obj);
    }
    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        this._gateway.Post(typeof(T), obj);
    }
    public void Save(T obj)
    {
        this._gateway.Post(typeof(T), obj);
    }
}


   //Logic lives elsewhere
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(Type type)
   {
      return Connect().GetAsync(Path(type)).Result;
   }
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(Type type, dynamic obj)
   {
      return Connect().PostAsync(Path(type), obj);
   }
    private string Path(Type type)
    {
        var className = type.Name;
        return "api/service/" + Application.Key + "/" + className;
    }
    private HttpClient Connect()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("X");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return client;
    }
```

I use generics to determine where it needs to fire once it hit's the gateway.
So if the `Type` is **Category** it will fire the **Category** service thus calling:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> FindAll(string appKey, string cls)
{
    var response = ConnectTo.Service(appKey, cls);
    return (appKey == Application.Key) ? (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ? response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<dynamic>>().Result : null : null;
}
```

The Gateway does not contain the physical files/Class's of the types.

After a little code, I was hoping someone could give me a little demonstration or the best approach to handle security/user authentication with the current architecture.

**Case Scenario 1**
User hits the web app and logs in, at that point the users encrypted email and password is sent to the `Gateway API` which is then passed to the `User Service` and decides whether the user is authenticated - all well and good but now I want to fetch all Messages from the `Message Service` that the user has received. I cannot really say in the Gateway if the user is authenticated, fetch the messages because that does not solve the issue of calling the `Message Service` outside of the `Gateway API`

I also cannot add authentication to each individual service because that would require all respective services talking to the `User Service` and that defeats the purpose of the pattern.

**Fixes:**
Only allow the Gateway to call the Services. Requests to services outside of the Gateway should be blocked.

I know security is a broad topic but within the current context, I'm hoping someone could direct me with the best course of action to resolve the issue.

Currently I have Hardcoded a `Guid` in all off the applications, which in turn fetches data if the app is equal.

Comment: There are thousands of question about authentication and authorization, what did your research show? Of course anything static (like a GUID) is no security at all, as someone can simply sniff the GUID from network traffic and build their own app which will also send the same GUID.

Comment: I'm very familiar with Authentication and Authorization in monolithic applications. The architecture poses challenges. Have you implemented the Micro Service architecture before? Guid approach is Temp.

Comment: Do you need to authenticate your clients(apps) or resource owners?

Comment: What is the meaning of the client authentication when you doesn't want to restrict access to part of your resource?

Comment: Apologies, spent an incredible amount of time coding - having a mental block haha Give me a few mins to re-phrase.

Comment: That you implemented your service using microservices is irrelevant to your clients. All that your clients see is the gateway, so they authenticate against the gateway. Or do you mean that the gateway is to be transparent and that each service behind it does its own authentication and authorization?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for your comment, Q edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit***

*This answer is about the Gateway <-> Micro service communication. The user should of course be properly authenticated when the App talks with the gateway*

***end edit***

First of all, the micro services should not be reachable from internet. They should only be accessible from the gateway (which can be clustered).

Second, you do need to be able to identify the current user. You can do it by passing the `UserId` as a HTTP header. Create a WebApi filter which takes that header and creates a custom `IPrincipal` from it.

Finally you need some way to make sure that the request comes from the gateway or another micro service. An easy way to do that is to use HMAC authentication on a token.

Store the key in the `web.config` for each service and the gateway. Then just send a token with each request (which you can authenticate using a WebApi authentication filter)

To generate a hash, use the `HMACSHA256` class in .NET:

```
private static string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
{
    secret = secret ?? "";
    var keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
    var messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    using (var hasher = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
    {
        var hashmessage = hasher.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
    }
}
```

So in your `MicroServiceClient` you would do something like this:

```
var hash = CreateToken(userId.ToString(), mySharedSecret);
var myHttpRequest = HttpRequest.Create("yourUrl");
myHttpRequest.AddHeader("UserId", userId);
myHttpRequest.AddHeader("UserIdToken", hash);
//send request..
```

And in the micro service you create a filter like:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    protected string SharedSecret
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedSecret"]; }
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var userId = context.Request.Headers.GetValues("UserId").FirstOrDefault();
            if (userId == null)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, context.Request);
                return;
            }

            var userIdToken = context.Request.Headers.GetValues("UserIdToken").FirstOrDefault();
            if (userIdToken == null)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, context.Request);
                return;
            }

            var token = CreateToken(userId, SharedSecret);
            if (token != userIdToken)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, context.Request);
                return;
            }


            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userId, "CustomIdentification"),
                new[] {"ServiceRole"});
            context.Principal = principal;
        });
    }

    public async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    private static string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
    {
        secret = secret ?? "";
        var keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
        var messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        using (var hasher = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            var hashmessage = hasher.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, let me craft a request with the `UserId: admin` header.

Comment: @CodeCaster: If you have managed to get access to the gateway server, don't you think that you could hurt the system in several other ways?

Comment: The first rule of network protocols is: don't trust the sender (well, at least after SMTP, FTP and HTTP were invented...). OP is talking about desktop and mobile apps talking to a webservice. You can never trust any network to be free of malicious users, so you need every user to authenticate themselves, from the app.

Comment: Or if you host supports it, like Azure you can set your API to internal so it can only be accessed by VM's running in your Azure Services. Also I agree with @jgauffin on the fact that the micro service has to trust the gateway, once the trust with the gateway is established you don't need to verify everything it says.

Comment: @CodeCaster: the authentication is done between the app <-> gateway. My answer is about gateway <-> micro services.

Comment: @jgauffin Thank you for the demonstration, I wont use the exact logic but more understanding of the process. Thank you again.

Comment: That's great. Understanding is the most important part. The code is just a help on the way to understanding.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 (Preferred)**

The easy way is the micro services should be behind the gateway, hence you would whitelist services to connect to them, meaning only authorized and trusted parties have access (i.e. the gateway only). Clients shouldn't have direct access to them. The Gateway is your night club bouncer.

**Option 2**

You can use a JWT or some form of token and share the secret key between the services. I use JWT Authorization Bearer tokens.

The other services don't need to query the user service, they just need to know that the token is valid, then they have authorization to use the API. I get the JWT passed from the client to the gateway and inject it into the request that is sent to the other service behind, just a straight pass through.

The micro service behind needs to have the same JWT consumption as the gateway for authorization but as I mentioned that is just determining a valid token, not querying a valid user.

But this has an issue that once someone is authorized they can jump call upon other users data unless you include something like a claim in the token.

**My Thoughts**

The part that I found a challenge from Monolithic to Micro Services was that you needed to switch where you place your trust. In Monolithic you control everything you are in charge. The point of Micro Services is that other services are in complete control of their domain. You have to place your trust in that other service to fulfill its obligations and not want to recheck and reauthorize everything at every level beyond what is necessary.

Comment: Ok, finished my editing. Hopefully that explains it.

Comment: Thank you for your time.